# Concatenation of Strings and characters

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

The following statements,

```
String string = "string";   

string = string +((char)65) + 5;
System.out.println(string);
```

Produce the output `stringA5`.

---

The following however,

```
String string = "string";

string += ((char)65) + 5;
System.out.println(string);
```

Produce `string70`.

Where is the difference?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You see this behavior as a result of the combination of operator precedence and string conversion.

[JLS 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1-100) states:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

Therefore the right hand operands in your first expression are implicitly converted to string: `string = string + ((char)65) + 5;`

For the second expression however `string += ((char)65) + 5;` the `+=` compound assignment operator has to be considered along with `+`. Since `+=` is weaker than `+`, the `+` operator is evaluated first. There we have a `char` and an *int* which results in a [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to `int`. Only then `+=` is evaluated, but at this time the result of the expression involving the `+` operator has already been evaluated.

Answer (score 16):

**Case 1**

```
string = string +((char)65) + 5;
```

everything is treated as String but in second case

Sequence of operation performed:

- `string +((char)65 = stringA`
- `stringA + 5 = stringA5`

**Case 2**

```
 string += ((char)65) + 5;
```

first right hand side is calculated means first operation will be like `((char)65) + 5`, So result of `((char)65) + 5 is 70` and after that += operation.

Sequence of operation performed:

- `(char)65 + 5 = 70`
- `string + 70 = string70`

**Lets see 1 more example**

```
String string = "string";
string += ((char)65) + 5 + "A";
System.out.println(string);
```

**Output** string70A

**Reason**
Same first right hand side is calculated and sequesce of opertion performed is

- `(char)65 + 5 = 70`
- `70 + "A" = 70A`
- `string  + 70A = string70A`

Comment: So, does it have to do something with the operator precedence?

Comment: Yes, Operation is always performed on the basis of operator precedence. += these type of operator are resolved after complition of right side evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

When you write:

```
string = string + ((char)65) + 5;
```

It is like writing:

```
String string =
     new StringBuilder(string).append((char)65).append((int)5).toString();
```

Which is like appending `string` to `A` (The char representation of the decimal 65) and `5`.

In the latter, you're first calculating the right hand, and then adding the result to `string`, it's like writing:

```
string = string + 70;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string = string +((char)65) + 5;
```

This means "Set string to the concatenation of `string`, `((char)65)`, and `5`." This gets evaluated from left-to-right (so first `string + ((char)65)`, then that `+5`, and concatenation of a string and an integer converts that integer to a string.

```
string += ((char)65) + 5;
```

This means "Calculate the result of `((char)65)+5` and add it to string" - the entire right-hand side is evaluated before adding the result to the string. Since a `char` is really just a 16-bit integer, it adds them together as integers - giving 70 - and then it appends that to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same case as the example:

```
System.out.println("abc"+10 + 5);
```

produces abc105 (add as String)

and

```
System.out.println(5 + 10);
```

produces 15 (add as Number)

The `String` included in the (first place of the) operation forces all the elements to be treated as `Strings` while executing the operation. In your case with `+=` however, the operation is executed first in the right part (treating the elements as `int`) because of the operator precedence and then is concatenated with the `String`.