# Do I need to cast to String when adding an Integer or a Double to a String?

Tags: java, casting

If I have

```
'String t = "";
int i = 1;
double d = 3.3;'
```

May I do
    `t = t + " " + i + " " + d`
or I need to cast?

Comment: try it baby. try it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20516774/2864740

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but I still wanted to understand if this was just an incorrect but working trick or the real good way of programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can..No need to cast..

Simply you can do like you said, `t = t + " " + i + " " + d;`

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't

```
t = t + " " + i + " " + d --> "New" String = string + " " + String.valueOf(integer) + " " + String.valueOf(double)
```

Comment: I have 2 answers, one saying I can, one saying I can't.
I know both work, but is this one more correct or equivalent?

Comment: @Tatanan - I meant.. "No, you don't have to cast it".

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
    double total = 10; 
    String total = String.valueOf(total);
```

Comment: how is this related to the question?